# Adding several columns at the same time with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe with a variable number of columns and with are handled inside MultiIndex for the columns. I'm trying to add several columns into the same MultiIndex structure

I've tried to add the new columns like if I would if there was only one column but it doesn't work

I have tried this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,2), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('plus_zero', 'A'), ('plus_zero', 'B')]))

df['plus_one'] = df['plus_zero'] + 1
```

But I get `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`.

The original `df` should look like this:

```
  plus_zero          
          A         B
0  0.602891  0.701130
1  0.395749  0.960206
2  0.268238  0.140606
3  0.165802  0.971707
```

And the result I want:

```
  plus_zero            plus_one          
          A         B         A         B
0  0.602891  0.701130  1.602891  1.701130
1  0.395749  0.960206  1.395749  1.960206
2  0.268238  0.140606  1.268238  1.140606
3  0.165802  0.971707  1.165802  1.971707
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

You must specify the names of the new columns and the `axis=1` or `axis='columns'`

```
pd.concat([df.loc[:,'plus_zero'],df.loc[:,'plus_zero']+1],
          keys=['plus_zero','plus_one'],
          axis=1)
```

```
  plus_zero            plus_one          
          A         B         A         B
0  0.049735  0.013907  1.049735  1.013907
1  0.782054  0.449790  1.782054  1.449790
2  0.148571  0.172844  1.148571  1.172844
3  0.875560  0.393258  1.875560  1.393258
```